# GAS: PropertiesService with token is null for PropertiesService

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api

What is the correct way to use the OAuth token with Google App Script to use **PropertiesService**?

I build an application with slack and **work well if I don't use this source code**.

If I try to use this then result token is null:

```
const token = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('xoxb-slack-token');
Logger.log(token)
...
Info    null
```

Comment: null usually means the property doesn't exist.  Did you setProperty(key,value) somewhere?

Comment: I don't set any properties. I suppose are slack API properties.

Comment: How do they get into the PropertiesService Script Properties?  These properties are only for that script so your script has to some how put the properties into PropertiesService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script's [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) can be used to store and retrieve data on your script.

If you don't first store them (for example, via [setProperty(key,value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperty(String,String))), you cannot retrieve them.

So, in this case, you should first get whatever data is coming from Slack and store it as Apps Script properties, if you want to retrieve them later in your script, using this service.

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)